# reading terms in Prolog

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I have to do a small program to work with sets like `A = {3,5,1,8}`. A set like this can be made by the facts:

```
set(a,3)
set(a,5) 
set(a,1) 
set(a,8)
```

and I've got these domains and this fact:

```
domains 
name=symbol
element=integer 

facts
set(name,element)
```

Now I have to implement a function that lets the user add new sets, but I have to use the predicate "readterm" to read the sets from the keyboard and I've got no idea how to use it :S

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: you're using visual prolog right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some documentation on readterm: http://www.aistudy.com/program/prolog/visual_prolog/Handling%20terms%20in%20text%20files.htm